# Como ordenar fecha cuando el mes es en letra

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Estoy tratando de ordenar esta fecha, pero me arroja Invalid date

```
let carpetas = [
          {
              "name": "2023-enero-2",
          },
          {
              "name": "2023-enero-1",
          },
          {
              "name": "2023-enero-8",
          }
      ]
```

para manejar las fechas como que no es correcto este formato new Date("2023-enero-2") arroja Invalid date

he tratado de ordenarlo así pero tampoco

```
  console.log(carpetas.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.name).getTime() > new Date(b.name).getTime()));
```

Comment: Por favor lee la documentación sobre el objeto `Date` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debe reformatear las fechas para que sean válidas. Entonces podemos ordenarlos.

```js
let carpetas = [
  {
    name: "2023-enero-2"
  },
  {
    name: "2023-enero-1"
  },
  {
    name: "2023-enero-8"
  }
];

// Une matriz de meses en español
const meses = [
  "enero",
  "febrero",
  "marzo",
  "abril",
  "mayo",
  "junio",
  "julio",
  "agosto",
  "septiembre",
  "octubre",
  "noviembre",
  "diciembre"
];

// Una función para sumar ceros
const agregaLosCeros = (n) => (+n < 10 ? "0" : "") + n;

// Una función para formatear fechas correctamente en ISO (YYYY-MM-DD)
const carpetasConIso = carpetas.map((carpeta) => {

  // Compruebe si la fecha tiene el formato esperado...
  if(!carpeta.name.match(/\d{4}-[a-z]+-\d{1,2}/)){
    throw new Error(`"${carpeta.name}" mal formada.`)
  }
  
  const partes = carpeta.name.split("-");
  // Lanzar un error si no se encuentra el mes
  if (meses.indexOf(partes[1]) === -1) {
    throw new Error(`"${partes[1]}" no encontrado en la matriz de meses.`);
  }

  partes[1] = agregaLosCeros(meses.indexOf(partes[1]) + 1);
  partes[2] = agregaLosCeros(partes[2]);
  carpeta.iso = partes.join("-");

  return carpeta;
});

// Ordene aqui, sin ".getTime()"
const resultado = carpetasConIso.sort(
  (a, b) => new Date(a.iso) - new Date(b.iso)
);

console.log(resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que darle formato a tus fechas del objeto para que puedas ordenarlas por el día, lo que se me ocurre es crear un objeto con los meses y hacer un `forEach()` a tu arreglo `carpeta` para modificar el día y el mes, es decir, el nombre del mes se reemplaza por el valor del objeto `meses` y el día se agrega un "0" a la izquierda cuando supere los 2 dígitos con `padStart()` (o sea, del 1 al 9 se agrega 0 a la izquierda, del 10 en adelante ya no porque son 2 dígitos). Y ahora con el arreglo obtenido (ya formateado las fechas), para ordenarlo por el día debes obtener el día con `getDate()` y ordenarlo con `sort()`, así:

```js
const carpetas = [
  {
    "name": "2023-enero-2",
  },
  {
    "name": "2023-enero-1",
  },
  {
    "name": "2023-enero-8",
  }
]

const meses = {
  "enero": "01",
  "febrero": "02",
  "marzo": "03",
  "abril": "04",
  "mayo": "05",
  "junio": "06",
  "julio": "07",
  "agosto": "08",
  "septiembre": "09",
  "octubre": "10",
  "noviembre": "11",
  "diciembre": "12",
};

carpetas.forEach(carpeta => {
  const [anio, mes, dia] = carpeta.name.split("-");
  carpeta.name = `${anio}-${mes}-${dia.padStart(2, "0")}`;
  carpeta.name = carpeta.name.replace(mes, meses[mes]);
});

console.log("==================== arreglo formateado ====================");
console.log(carpetas);

carpetas.sort((a, b) => {
  const [anioA, mesA, diaA] = a.name.split("-");
  const [anioB, mesB, diaB] = b.name.split("-");
  const dateA = new Date(anioA, mesA, diaA);
  const dateB = new Date(anioB, mesB, diaB);
  return dateA.getDate() - dateB.getDate();
});

console.log("==================== arreglo ordenado ====================");
console.log(carpetas);
```